# How to show a sheet before multiple AlertSounds finishes?

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to show a sheet before the alert sounds with `sleep` and `for` loop multiple times finish.

In my code, the sheet appears after alert sounds finish playing.

How could I do this?

---

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AudioToolbox

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("SOUND and OPEN SHEET")
                .padding()
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isSheet.toggle()
            for _ in 1...2{
                AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(1151,nil)
                sleep(2)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheet){
            Sheet()
        }
    }
}

struct Sheet: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Sheet")
            .padding()
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play sound in background, like

```
    .onTapGesture {
        isSheet.toggle()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {      // << this !!
            for _ in 1...2{
                AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(1151,nil)
                sleep(2)
            }
        }
    }
```